# Should I replace an existing gas fireplace with electric?

Tags: electrical, fireplace, gas

Does it make sense to replace my existing gas fireplace with a newer electrical one?  Would the new electrical one require less maintenance?  Would it run more efficiently and in doing so cost less to operate?

location = US / IL

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty subjective question, so it will probably get closed.  However, generally speaking, gas is cheaper than electricity for heating purposes, i.e., it takes less $ worth of gas than electric to heat "whatever", so the cost will most likely be lower for the gas one.  Heating is not a particularly efficient use of electricity.

Comment: This depends on your location, but in general in the US you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Gas fireplaces don't require much maintenance.  You also get the benefit of a more natural looking flame (although the modern electrics are pretty impressive).